# Ionic.Zip extract files and ignore password

Tags: c#, compact-framework, pocketpc, ionic-zip

I am using **Ionic.Zip** (Compact Framework version) in my Pocket-PC project.
Extracting zipped files (using Ionic.Zip) are working properly. If I put password on the compressed file, it requires the password before extracting, but when I try this instance, password validation for extraction fails.

Example: This folder is about to compress.

```
\MyDevice\My Documents\My Pictures
```

This folder contains two files `('Flower.jpg','Waterfall.jpg')`
Compressing the file using this code:

```
public string Compress(string[] Paths, string SaveFileName, string Password, string CompressionType)
{
    try
    {
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
                zip.Password = Password;
            zip.CompressionLevel = Utility.GetCompressionLevel(CompressionType);
            foreach (string item in Paths)
            {
                if (Utility.IsDirectory(item))
                    zip.AddDirectory(item);
                else if (Utility.IsFile(item))
                    zip.AddFile(item);
            }
            if (!SaveFileName.Trim().ToLower().EndsWith(".zip"))
                if (SaveFileName.Trim().EndsWith("."))
                    SaveFileName += "zip";
                else
                    SaveFileName += ".zip";

            zip.Save(SaveFileName);
        }
        return Utility.GetResourceString("ZipSuccess");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Extraction code:

```
public string Decompress(string ZipFilePath, string TargetPath, string Password, bool OverwriteExistingFiles)
{
    try
    {
        using (ZipFile decompress = ZipFile.Read(ZipFilePath))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
                decompress.Password = Password;

            foreach (ZipEntry e in decompress)
            {
                e.Extract(TargetPath, OverwriteExistingFiles ? ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently : ExtractExistingFileAction.DoNotOverwrite);
            }
        }
        return Utility.GetResourceString("ExtractSuccess");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Extracting the file in this location works great, because it requires password:

```
\MyDevice\My Documents\Personal
```

But! When I extract the file on the same folder:

```
\MyDevice\My Documents\My Pictures
```

It extract the files without requiring the password.
I think this is a bug. What can I do for this?
Hope someone could answer. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the files get extracted? Your are extracting them to the same folder where you compressed the files. So the files already exist in this folder

Comment: Yes, I also tried renaming the files before extracting to make it sure that files are being extracted. I also put break point on the foreach loop, to see if there are collected files to extract.

Comment: If you think it is a bug, you should post that here: http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in your Compress() method.  When compressing your files, the Password property of the ZipFile instance is never set.  Take a look at your logic that decides whether or not to assign the zip.Password property.

It reads:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
    zip.Password = Password;
```

As written, the zip.Password property will be set only if the Password parameter is null or an empty string.  If the Password parameter is a non-blank string, the code skips zip.Password assignment statement.

The if-statement in your Compress() method is missing a **not** operator.  It should read:

```
if ( ! string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
    zip.Password = Password
```

Comment: This was my project last March this year. Actually, I presented my project carefully without showing the bug. Thanks to God, I passed!